# Custom asset compilation in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, asset-pipeline

My project structure is:

```
myProject
              |
              - ember app
              |
              - my addon
```

I am developing a product where I have to integrate with 3 or more products. Each integration requires only specific functionalities.I have all my features as components in my addon. Now I have installed my addon in my ember app. So there is an entry in package.json. So the whole addon will be available in the vendor.js file. For example, if my 1st product integration requires only 3 components from my addon , I am expected to give only those 3 components dependencies. But since I have entry in package.json,I am  giving the whole addon. I want to take the entry of my addon from my app package.json, and write only the 3 components in to one file viz..., product1.js etc...For the next integration I will pick only the components required for that integration and write it as produc2.js. In this way I can remove the unnecessary things in the script.And respective integration will include it as a script from their end. So is there any way to satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, but you'll have to work a bit to make it happen. You'll need to pass flags from the consuming app to your addon using the `ember-cli-build.js` file. And then in your addon's index.js file you'll need to watch for those flags and use Broccoli to filter down to the appropriate files that you want included in the vendor file.

It's not overly complicated to do, but the Broccoli documentation is relatively sparse at the moment. Would suggest watching videos on this from various conferences and consulting other addons that do it similarly.